# Remove symlink with Ansible

Tags: ansible, symbolic-link, symlink

I have a dead symlink named `dead_symlink` under the directory `/usr/local/bin`

When Ansible check the file it reports it exists

```
- stat: "path=/usr/local/bin/dead_symlink"
  register: dead_symlink_bin

- debug: var=dead_symlink_bin.stat.exists
```

But when I try to remove it, it reports 'ok' but nothing is happening (the symlink is still there)

```
- name: Remove symlink
  file:
    path: "path=/usr/local/bin/dead_symlink"
    state: absent
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: run the tas in debug `-vv` and add the output to your question. The command is IMHO correct.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have a synatx error in your task. It should be:

```
- name: Remove symlink
  file:
   path: "/usr/local/bin/dead_symlink"
   state: absent
```

Ansible is probably looking for the path `path=/usr/local/bin/dead_symlink` and not for `/usr/local/bin/dead_symlink`.

Comment: hahaha, true! feel so stupid for a typo... And I've spend some hours on that... Thanks again!

Comment: yeah, looks like a simple copy&paste mistake. I still wonder why Ansible interpreted that as a vaild path. First step should be always to run in debug than you can see the commands Ansible is executing.

Comment: Yes it was a copy paste mistake from the `- stat: "path=/usr/local/bin/dead_symlink"`. I run the debug, I read many times the output but I stack and never see it :P Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

For me in playbook

```
- name: Deleting Default Configurations
  when: sitelink is success
  file: path=/etc/nginx/site-enabled/default state=absent
```

above code is working nice for me just replace with your path.